# Semi transparent image background in Android shape xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-shape

I want to make a rectange object (shape) with gradient and below it image background. I've got:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#BF0e2634"
        android:endColor="#BF0e2634"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#0e2634" >
    </stroke>

    <size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp"/>



    <corners android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"/>
</shape></item>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/galaxy"
        android:alpha="0.2"
      />

    </layer-list>
```

But the image is overide the rectange with stroke and gradient. Please help me guys!

Comment: You need to describe what you want more.  Do you want the image on top of the rectangle semi transparent?  The rectangle on top of the image?  The image inset into this rectangle?  Right now you're getting what I'd expect-  you have no alpha set on the image, so its going to overwrite the rest of the shape.

Comment: if you want image below it, you should list it before your shape not after

Comment: Switch your shapes.

Comment: please add the image coming after compiling to understand better.